# How can I run state.sls from a reactor

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, webhooks, salt-stack

**TL;DR**

I want to use the reactor, to call something similar to a simple `salt '*' state.sls examplestate`

---

I'm new(ish) to saltstack reactors, and I'm having issues with one of the features.

In the reactor documents located [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/), under "Advanced State System Capabilities", there is the following example:

**/etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf**

```
# A custom event containing: {"foo": "Foo!", "bar: "bar*", "baz": "Baz!"}
reactor:
  - myco/custom/event:
    - /srv/reactor/some_event.sls
```

**/srv/reactor/some_event.sls**

```
invoke_orchestrate_file:
  runner.state.orchestrate:
    - mods: orch.do_complex_thing
    - pillar:
        event_tag: {{ tag }}
        event_data: {{ data | json() }}
```

**/srv/salt/orch/do_complex_thing.sls**

```
{% set tag = salt.pillar.get('event_tag') %}
{% set data = salt.pillar.get('event_data') %}

# Pass data from the event to a custom runner function.
# The function expects a 'foo' argument.
do_first_thing:
  salt.runner:
    - name: custom_runner.custom_function
    - foo: {{ data.foo }}

# Wait for the runner to finish then send an execution to minions.
# Forward some data from the event down to the minion's state run.
do_second_thing:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: {{ data.bar }}
    - sls:
      - do_thing_on_minion
    - pillar:
        baz: {{ data.baz }}
    - require:
      - salt: do_first_thing
```

In this example, assuming that I'm following it correctly, the reactor `event` sets off the `some_event.sls` located in the reactor directory.  The `some_event.sls` then uses runner.state.orchestrate to run `do_complex_thing.sls`.

What I'm trying to do is very similar but I've been unable to make it work.  I'd like to have the reactor `event` set off `some_event.sls`.  In some_event.sls I'd just like it to call a state that I've written.  For example, a simple state that uses file.managed to move a file from the master, to the minion.  I've attempted this below:

**/etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf**

```
reactor:
  - 'salt/netapi/hook/test':
    - /srv/reactor/testdirectory/configure.sls
```

**/srv/reactor/testdirectory/configure.sls**

```
{% set postdata = data.get('post', {}) %}
{% if grains['os_family']=="Debian" %}
testifthisworks:
  salt.state:
    - mods: transferfile.init
    - tgt: {{ postdata.tgt }}
{% endif %}
```

**/srv/salt/transferfile/init.sls**

```
/root/testfile.txt:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://testfiles/testfile.txt
    - makedirs: True
    - mode: 700
    - template: jinja
```

In the configure.sls file, I'm trying to use salt.state to kick off the state.sls, this isn't working with the error `"ReactWrap" object has no attribute salt`

When I try to do the same thing, but using the runner.state.orchestrate from the original example (I dont need orchestrate), it works, but it moves the file to /root/ on my master.

I'm not sure what I can use other than salt.state to just run state.sls.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

/srv/reactor/testdirectory/configure.sls

```
{% set postdata = data.get('post', {}) %}
{% if grains['os_family']=="Debian" %}
testifthisworks:
  local.state.sls:
    - tgt: {{ postdata.tgt }}
    - arg:
      - transferfile
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried, that and it didn't work (not sure why), but Whytewolf did have the answer on the IRC.  I'll post the answer below.  +1 for adding the local.state.sls though.

Comment: You might try removing the `mods` line from my example and add the 2 lines of the `arg` section you have in the following example.

I'm pretty sure you don't need the   `.init`

Comment: That is correct, I removed the .init (it works fine with it, but yeah, doesn't need it) and it works that way as well.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I'll add that change to my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way I got this to work was to change the `/srv/reactor/testdirectory/configure.sls` to the following:

```
{% set postdata = data.get('post', {}) %}
{% if grains['os_family']=="Debian" %}
testifthisworks:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: {{ postdata.tgt }}
    - arg:
      - transferfile
```

And now everything works.